# React Router 4 Optional parameter with custom path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have this route below that loads a dashboard component:

```
<Route
  path={`${match.url}/dashboard`}
  render={params => <Dashboard {...params} />}
/>
```

Now, I want to add an optional parameter that would only be valid if it's being preceded by an additional path (e.g. additional-path/:param). I tried the code below but I'm not getting the value of the optional param:

```
<Route
  path={`${match.url}/dashboard/(filter/:filtername)?`}
  render={params => <Dashboard {...params} />}
/>
```

Could somebody tell me whats wrong with the code below?

Answer (score 6):

In older versions of React Router you would define optional parameters with parentheses, for example:
`` `${match.url}/dashboard/filter(/:filtername)` ``

For React Router V4 you define the optional **filtername** parameter with a trailing **?** like this:

```
<Route 
  path={ `${match.url}/dashboard/filter/:filtername?` } 
  render={ params => <Dashboard { ...params } /> } 
/>
```

Or you can define multiple optional parameters, **filter** and **filtername**, like this:

```
<Route 
  path={ `${match.url}/dashboard/:filter?/:filtername?` } 
  render={ params => <Dashboard { ...params } /> } 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use path param optional on **react-router 4** like that:

```
<Route exact path="/account" component={Orders} />

<Route exact path="/account/orders?" component={Orders} />
```

So to define a parameter as optional you add a trailing question-mark (?). Also for multiple optional parameters:

```
<Route path="/account/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?" component={Orders} />
```

---